# Trying to do an inner join with a column and some of the values in that column anything

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g

As the title states I'm tryin to do an inner join with two tables. For one of the tables you have a column with normal values populating it. However, for the other table the values populating are usually normal, but sometimes its populated with '-' which means everything.

So I want to do an inner join where if there is a '-' it will join with everything in the other table. Is that a thing I can do with SQL (I'm using Oracle btw), but do the normal inner join operation if its a normal non '-' value.

```
t1:
A | B
1 | 2
- | 4
3 | 5



t2:
A | C
1 | 4
6 | 6


t3: result of inner join
A | B | C
1 | 2 | 4
1 | 4 | 4
6 | 4 | 6
```

Any suggestions? Any and all is help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would be:

```
select t2.a, t1.b, t2.c
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.a = t2.a or t1.a = '-';
```

Note that `or` can sometimes be hard to optimize for performance.  So, you might find this faster using `union all`:

```
select t2.a, t1.b, t2.c
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.a = t2.a
union all
select t2.a, t1.b, t2.c
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.a = '-';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9c30b52dbb055dd72f2407ec3d190e31) is a db<>fiddle.